# How to evenly unwrap / texture long extruded objects with folds and uneven segments?

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

I've some difficulties to find a satisfactory unwrap solution for this kind of long angled object with uneven segments:

[image]

I'm only interested in the brown faces which are delimited by two seams.

The solution must preserve the relative length of each straight segment, so that the texture containing a repeated pattern can be mapped evenly on the whole length (the sample is a ceramic [baseboard](https://www.atrimglobal.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/LINE-CANELA-PARED.jpg)).

Here is the result with a cube projection and a checker texture, other methods provide different results, but the distortion is always present:

[image]

I can't find a solution, except purely manual, to create the UV map while ensuring all segments:

- Are oriented in the same direction on the map,
- Have their length proportional to their actual size, to prevent texture distortion.

These constraints seem quite common, is there a standard approach?

Intuitively, I'm expecting the most simple method to lead to overlapping variable length rectangles, in the same direction, anchored at a corner (or a very large single rectangle).

---

[image]

Comment: Do you have trouble unwrapping this at all or do you just search for a more convenient/automated solution than making a seam for each edge?

Comment: What do you mean with "purely manual". Is it setting the right seams?

Comment: @bstnhnsl (and josh): Marking the seams is ok, but whatever the unwrap method I tested, either segments are not scaled properly (leading to texture being deformed between segments) or are not oriented along the same U/V axis (leading to texture being at right angle). By "manually" I mean unwrapping using whatever method and then relocating each UV vertex at the appropriate location (and calculating the relative length of each baseboard segment). I'm a beginner, I may have missed something obvious.

Comment: Could you upload your .blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ? I'll have a look and give you some tips

Comment: @bstnhnsl: Thanks a lot, https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5238/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First step:**

See the different values under "Scale" on the right side?
Your model is stretched in different directions.

[image]

for unwrapping to work correctly, apply the scale (the numbers for x,y and z should all be 1).
select your object -> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> -> Apply Scale

[image]

**Next**

As you don't care about the blue backside, create a seam on the outside of the blue Part.
<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>rmb</kbd> might help a lot in edge select mode (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>).

[image]

If you unwrap now, the image will still be distorted. so we need to add one more little step:

We need to create seems in every corner. You don't need to go all the way to the bottom though – only as long as the tilted faces on the top go. This way your texture is continuous all the way through (you might or might not want that – if you don't, extend the seams to the bottom).

[image]

now select everything -> <kbd>u</kbd> -> unwrap

depending on the project i often get better results if I change the unwrapping method to "conformal" on the left panel.

[image]

The final UV in the Image Editor (The blue backsides on the bottom aren't 100% straight, but you don't care, right?):

[image]

And the Object in Material View:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Let me know, if you have any questions.

Comment: Woo! that's an impressive correcting with helpful explanations. Thanks, it answers *exactly* my question!

Comment: How come the unwrapping isn't 100% straight as you mentioned? Is it because the mesh isn't straight, or is it just a Blender quirk?

Comment: The unwrapping of the backside isn't clean. there are some seams missing for it to unwrap perfectly. The back, the bottom and the sides are still connected without seams.