# Unwrap Faces Without Distortion

Tags: texturing, uv

Is it possible to unwrap a series of connected faces and make them keep their proportions relative to each other for precise texture placement?

I have a wall structure that has rounded corners, and when I unwrap it, the faces do not keep their proportions relative to each other, resulting in distorted/stretched textures when applied.

There must be a way to make faces keep their relative size.

I attached an image that hopefully illustrates my problem:

[image]

Comment: did you "apply scale" in object mode?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=unwrap+distortion

Comment: I have read most of these but not all. I’ll see if I can find and answer and if so, I will delete my question.

Comment: Instead of deleting, add more information, and maybe a link to your file.

Comment: I've found the solution in this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118273/how-to-evenly-unwrap-texture-long-extruded-objects-with-folds-and-uneven-segme (it was hard to find because it doesn't have a good title and was ranked at the bottom). Anyway, mine is clearly a duplicate. What would be the best course of action? Delete? Or add more detail and answer it, so people can find it more easily in the future than the other answer?

Comment: Don't delete. just mark as duplicate. This post might help others find solutions for a similar issue. Read: [should I delete my question?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/should-i-delete-my-question)